# Why dict.popitem() raises KeyError instead of returning None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there any benefit in `dict.popitem()` raising a`KeyError` exception when the dictionary is empty, instead of returning `None` (which is equivalent to Null) ?

```py
my_dict = {'color': 'blue', 'fruit': 'apple', 'pet': 'dog'}

while True:
    try:
        item = my_dict.popitem()
        print(f'{item} removed')
        # process the item here...
    except KeyError:
        print('The dictionary is empty !')
        break
```

Or is raising an exception instead of returning `None` considered more pythonic ?

Comment: Yes, raising exceptions is very pythonic. This isn't javascript where stuff just fails silently and you get null, or even more delightfully, undefined. Also, `None` is a totally valid value for a dictionary key, so how could you distinguish those two situations?

Comment: In general, it is an anti-pattern to mutate a dict this way until it is empty to process items one by one. just iterate throught the items in the dict, `for k,v in my_dict.items(): #process item`, if you need this dict reference to be cleared (major code smell imo), then just `my_dict.clear()` it at the end, `popitem`ing it in a loop is horribly inefficent

Comment: @Artyer ah, true. In any case, it is still pythonic for an exception to be raised in this situation rather than returning `None`. I can't think of any built-in container that works like that.

Comment: In any case, functions return `None` in python, conventionally, when they are mutator methods that have no return value, so `my_list.append(foo)` returns `None`. I would say it isn't pythonic for it to be used as a sentinel value, although, sometimes that ends up happening, if only for expediency,

Comment: Would `my_dict.popitem(defaultvalue=None)` be useful here?If it can't pop the item, it will simply return the default

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: You mention that it is not recommended to iterate using popitem(). Please refer this statement: _"popitem() is useful to destructively iterate over a dictionary, as often used in set algorithms."_, from: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Comment: @brainOverflow That is for stuff like tree traversal, which would add to the dict as well as popping from it. But you probably want a `list`, `collections.deque` or `set` of pairs in that case (For LIFO, FIFO and arbitrary-order queues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific method, it is normally used like this:

```
k, v = my_dict.popitem()
```

Which currently raises a `KeyError` when the dict is empty, and would be a `TypeError` if it had instead returned `None`.

Raising a `KeyError` would mean writing this:

```
try:
    k, v = my_dict.popitem()
except KeyError:
    # Dictionary is empty
else:
    # Process k, v

# Or

if my_dict:
    k, v = my_dict.popitem()
    # Process k, v
else:
    # Dictionary is empty
```

And returning `None`:

```
item = my_dict.popitem()
if item is not None:
    k, v = item
    # Process k, v
else:
    # Dictionary is empty
```

If the method returned `None`, you have to acknowledge the fact that the dictionary might be empty or get the cryptic `TypeError` that means less, whereas the `KeyError` is much more clear.

---

Raising an error can also show that that's not normally what happens. If you instead wrote something like this:

```
def do_stuff(my_dict):
    """Process an item from a dictionary (It must not be empty)"""
    k, v = my_dict.popitem()
    # do stuff
```

An appropriate error would be raised.

---

It can easily be implemented like this though:

```
item = my_dict.popitem() if my_dict else None
```

Comment: The one-liner 
`item = my_dict.popitem() if my_dict else None`
is very useful.